# Indexing error when comparing numbers in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing

I'm trying to build a function that given a list or string of numbers (for the string the numbers are separated by ",") and a target number finds the number of values in the last that can get to the target. Numbers can increase by 1 only by eating a number equal or smaller than themselves, after eating the smaller number the smaller number is removed from the list. The list resets to it's original for every number. I am close but I keep getting an index error and I'm not sure how to fix it

```py
def cannibal(l, target):

    newl = l
    count = 0
    i = 0
    listlen = len(newl)

    try:
        newl = l.split(",")
        newl.sort(reverse = True)
        newl = list(map(int, newl)) 
        print (newl)

    except:
        newl.sort(reverse = True)
        print (newl)

    finally:
        while i < len(newl):

            print ("index is ",i)

            if newl[i] == target:
                print ("match found at ", i)
                count += 1
                i += 1
                continue

            if newl[i] > target:
                i += 1
                continue

            for j in range(i+1,listlen-1):

                print ("list length is",listlen)
                while newl[i] > newl [j] and j<listlen:  

                    print (newl[i]," is eating ",newl[i+1])
                    newl.remove(newl [i+1])
                    newl[i] = newl[i]+1
                    listlen = len(newl)
                    print (newl)

                    if newl[i] == target:
                        print ("match found at ", i)
                        count += 1
                        i += 1
                        break
            i += 1


        print (count)
        return count
```

When `cannibal([27, 9, 3, 8, 11], 50)` is given it returns `IndexError: list index out of range` and points to `while newl[i] > newl [j] and j<listlen:`

Comment: Can u include the error message in ur post.

Comment: "listlen" is the length (number of characters) of the parameter "l" if it is a string. Probably you want it to be the number of items in the (later) "newl".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
>>> cannibal([27, 9, 3, 8, 11], 50)
[27, 11, 9, 8, 3]
index is  0
list length is 5
27  is eating  11
[28, 9, 8, 3]
28  is eating  9
[29, 8, 3]
29  is eating  8
[30, 3]
30  is eating  3
[31]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#169>", line 1, in <module>
    cannibal([27, 9, 3, 8, 11], 50)
  File "<pyshell#168>", line 36, in cannibal
    while newl[i] > newl [j] and j<listlen:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I ran the testcase you mentioned was failing. At first glance it looks like there is an improper exit condition. Upon further inspection, it seems like your innermost while loop is eventually forced to evaluate a condition that would raise an IndexError.

When I stick a `print(newl, i, j)` at the end of that while loop, here's what we get:

```py
>>> cannibal([27, 9, 3, 8, 11], 50)
[27, 11, 9, 8, 3]
index is  0
list length is 5
27  is eating  11
[28, 9, 8, 3]
[28, 9, 8, 3] 0 1
28  is eating  9
[29, 8, 3]
[29, 8, 3] 0 1
29  is eating  8
[30, 3]
[30, 3] 0 1
30  is eating  3
[31]
[31] 0 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#175>", line 1, in <module>
    cannibal([27, 9, 3, 8, 11], 50)
  File "<pyshell#174>", line 37, in cannibal
    while newl[i] > newl [j] and j<listlen:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Hopefully now it's clear what the issue is.

At a point during that while loop, you end up with `newl = [31]`, `i = 0`, and `j = 1`.

When the condition `while newl[i] > newl [j] and j<listlen` is evaluated, of course `newl[0] > newl[1]` is going to break the function because `newl[1]` doesn't exist.

To stop the error from *happening*, the easiest thing was to add a flag to break out of the for loop.

```py
def cannibal(l, target):

    newl = l
    count = 0
    i = 0
    listlen = len(newl)

    try:
        newl = l.split(",")
        newl.sort(reverse = True)
        newl = list(map(int, newl)) 
        print (newl)

    except:
        newl.sort(reverse = True)
        print (newl)

    finally:
        while i < len(newl):

            print ("index is ",i)

            if newl[i] == target:
                print ("match found at ", i)
                count += 1
                i += 1
                continue

            if newl[i] > target:
                i += 1
                continue

            break_out = False

            for j in range(i+1,listlen-1):

                if break_out: break

                print ("list length is",listlen)

                while newl[i] > newl [j] and j<listlen:  

                    print (newl[i]," is eating ",newl[i+1])
                    newl.remove(newl [i+1])
                    newl[i] = newl[i]+1
                    listlen = len(newl)
                    print (newl)
                    print(newl, i, j)
                    if newl[i] == target:
                        print ("match found at ", i)
                        count += 1
                        i += 1
                        print(newl, i, j)
                        break
                    if i >= len(newl) or j >= len(newl):
                        print ("loop is broken")
                        break_out = True
                        break
            i += 1


        print (count)
        return count
```

However, I believe the problem goes a little deeper. I don't entirely understand how you intended this function to work but I have a hunch you don't want `newl` to become `[31]` permanently after the first iteration of your for loop.

Comment: This worked to fix the first test case but when I used the test case cannibal([3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1], 4) it got the same error in the same place. Thank you for the explanation and the way to see indexing errors, I will start to use that

Comment: One simple way would be to swap the order of the tests: `while j < listlen and newl[i] > newl[j]` — Python evaluates `and` conditions in order, so in this case it would check `j < listlen` first, find that it's not the case, and skip the `new[j]` part of the test.